# Abnormally high hazard ratio and confidence intervals survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard

After running a recurrent events cox model with an interaction between time-dependent and time-independent covariates, the results are significant but also generate an abnormally high hazard ratio (6.767e+11) and CIs (1.924e+09, 2.380e+14). Is there a reason for this? Are the results invalid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This can happen when one coefficient is actually infinite. For example, if the oldest person available at each event time is the one who dies, then the coefficient for age will diverge to infinity. Try checking to see if that is the case for this covariate or interaction.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen Thank you so much for responding. I think this might be the time-independent covariate as it is essentially the proportion of time the event occurs over each episode of the event. Does this make the results invalid and not to be reported?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean about the time-independent covariate. In general if a coefficient is infinite it is invalid. But, depending on your application it might be better to report that this model didn't converge and then fit a model with that covariate removed.

Comment: You would need to provide a lot more detail about your data, your model, and the reported results to get a helpful answer. There are several ways such results could arise, and the ways to proceed would differ depending on the specific type of problem that led to this result.